# I want to change unity launcher in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ubuntu, unity, gsettings

I wrote `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom` in Ubuntu 17.10 but the result is:

> No such schema “com.canonical.Unity.Launcher”

What did I do wrong?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gnome/gsettings, so please correct the formatted command if I made a mistake with it.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 17.10 doesn't use Unity. It uses GNOME. From [an answer to the same question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/966935/616451):

> Go to System Settings and Select Dock from the Left Sidebar. In here, you'll see the option to move the Launcher (it's called Dock in Ubuntu 17.10) to bottom or to the right.
>
> [image]